# change the path of the log4j.properties for zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to change the path of `log4j.properties` file for zookeeper because I want to read this config file too from a central configuration folder, but I have not found any info on how to do it.

This is how I start zookeeper:

```
$1/bin/zkServer.sh start $2/zoo.cfg
```

where

- $1: the home directory of the unpacked zookeeper
- $2: holds the zookeeper config files

What I do now is a silly solution:

- Before I start zookeeper I copy this file to zookeeper home directory: `cp $2/log4j.properties $1/conf`

Is there any better way to configure the usage of an external log4j.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I assume you use the Zookeeper (and it's scripts) provided by [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka)

You need to export a variable before starting zookeeper

Here is the default

```
if [ "x$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$base_dir/../config/log4j.properties"
fi
```

So, you need to do

```
export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/your.properties"
zookeeper-server-start zoo.cfg &
```

It's best if you refactor these together into a `systemctl` service, though